# Query / Subquery with multiple date ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select

I'm trying to find a way to retrieve data using a sub query where weekly performance, as well as annual performance results are returned by customerid.  When the following statement is used, the results are total sales, as opposed to sales by customer ID (in each row).

```
Select CUSTOMERID, 
  SUM(Amount_Sales), 
  (Select SUM(Amount_Sales), 
   From SalesTable 
   Where SaleDate>='01/01/2017' 
     and SaleDate<='12/31/2017')
From SalesTable
Where SaleDate>='05/22/17' and SaleDate<='05/28/17'
GROUP BY CUSTOMERID
```

Comment: You have to use group by for CUSTOMERID

Comment: @Blasanka thanks for the heads up

Comment: In the future please keep these things in mind when posting: 1) Include a sample of the output you see as well as your desired output. 2) Please tag the question to a specific database engine. 3) Add the answer to your question when you figure it out if it isn't clear from someone else's comment.

Comment: not sure what you mean with your 3rd suggestion @spfursich.  Duly noted on the first two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a single aggregation using conditional aggregation:

```
select customerid,
    sum(amount_sales) as annual_sales,
    sum(case when saledate >= '2017-05-22'
                and saledate <= '2017-04-28' 
        then amount_sales else 0 end) as weekly_sales
from salestable
where saledate >= '2017-01-01'
    and saledate <= '2017-12-31'
group by customerid;
```

Comment: The where clause dates were changed to the entire year as opposed to weekly dates.  Was this by design?  performance related?

Comment: @BIGTONE559 - I switched the places of the date filters. Since your weekly filtered rows are a subset of the whole year, you can aggregate annually and *conditionally* aggregate weekly.